# Systemd path unit triggering on startup even if target file is unchanged

Tags: files, systemd, path

I'm trying to use a systemd path + service to trigger a python script when a file changes.

I'm finding that the script is triggered on startup, independent of when I change the file.

Here's the snippet of my .path file:

```
PathChanged=/home/pi/network/trigger.txt
Unit=monitor.service
```

currently while I'm testing, monitor.service simply triggers a script that writes to a log file with a timestamp.
here's a snippet of the log file:

```
 14:26:40 Friday September 3, 2021 file modified
```

and when I do stat /home/pi/network/trigger.txt,

```
Access: 2021-07-14 17:07:42.871258883 -0400
Modify: 2021-08-24 16:53:00.879999930 -0400
Change: 2021-08-24 16:53:00.879999930 -0400
```

Clearly then, the file hasn't been modified, yet the .path unit triggers on startup regardless. What's going on here?

Comment: Just confirming:  `monitor.service` doesn't have a `[Install] WantedBy=` does it?  I've seen people make that mistake before: enabling the service which should only be triggered by a path/socket.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I had enabled the service. This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path shouldn't trigger `monitor.service` on boot, but it's a common mistake to have `monitor.service` itself enabled on boot.

If `monitor.service` contains the usual:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then `monitor.service` will activate on boot **OR** whenever it gets triggers by your `*.path`.

#### Solution 1:

If this is a 3rd party service, then disable the service.  That will prevent it from activating on boot, but will not prevent it from being triggered by your `*.path`:

```
sudo systemctl disable monitor.service
```

#### Solution 2:

If you wrote `monitor.service` yourself, then simply delete the `[Install]` section from `monitor.service`.